# Convert nested SQL query to LINQ Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, subquery

Is there a way to accurately convert the following **SQL** query to **LINQ**

```
SELECT * FROM T1 
WHERE ColumnA IN (
    SELECT FkColumnA FROM T2 
    WHERE FkColumnB IN (
        SELECT ColumnB FROM T3 
        WHERE FkColumnC IN (
            SELECT ColumnC FROM T4 
            WHERE FkColumnD = 1)) AND FkColumnE is null AND ColumnF = 0)
```

Also, does anyone know of any **documentation** wherein any logic or guideline to convert SQL queries to LINQ is laid out?

**EDIT 1:**

The equivalent for the above using **JOINS** would be as below:

```
select * from T1  a
inner join T2 b on a.FKColumnA = b.ColumnA
inner join T3 c on c.ColumnB  = b.FkColumnB
inner join T4 d on d.ColumnC = c.FkColumnC
where a.FkColumnD is null and a.ColumnE = 0
and d.ColumnC = 1
```

and it's equivalent LINQ query would be

```
var linq = from q in context.T1
           join r in context.T2
           on q.FKColumnA equals r.ColumnA
           join s in context.T3 
           on r.FkColumnB equals s.ColumnB
           join t in context.T4 
           on s.FkColumnC equals t.ColumnC
           where q.FkColumnD != null && q.ColumnE == false && t.ColumnC == 56816
           select q.FkColumnF;
```

But using **JOINS** looked to be a bit more simpler and better in **LINQ**. Thus the question is for my knowledge purpose only.

Comment: Any reason you are using `IN` clauses rather than `JOIN`s?

Comment: No specific reason. I can do it with JOINS as well. This is just for my knowledge as with JOINS I know how to convert SQL to LINQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating your query literally, we get the following LINQ statement:

```
var results = table1.Where(t1 => table2.Where(
        t2 =>
            table3.Where(
                    t3 =>
                        table4.Where(t4 => t4.FkColumnD == 1)
                            .Select(t4 => t4.ColumnC)
                            .Contains(t3.FkColumnC))
                .Select(t3 => t3.ColumnB)
                .Contains(t2.FkColumnB) && !t2.FkColumnE.HasValue && t2.ColumnF == 0)
    .Select(t2 => t2.FkColumnA)
    .Contains(t1.ColumnA));
```

This results in an `IEnumerable<T1>` which you can use as required.

As far as I know there is no "documentation" on converting syntax, this, as a developer, is your job. However, I personally find [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) very useful when constructing LINQ statements.